# Parse.com REST API - Can I query a value within a subset of an Object data type column?

Tags: api, rest, object, parse-platform

I am a new user of Parse.com and do like what I see so far.  I am helping a friend out. They have a locations table that houses lat and long values. However, the developer that created it used an Object  data type instead of a GeoPoint data type to store lat/long info. The developer wrote an iOS app that pulls records from parse and stores them locally to display on the map.  What I am trying to do is figure out how that developer pulls only the records within X number of miles... or even based on a bounding box.  Anyways, my question is if I have an object column with data like what I have shown below is there any way to filter the results by lat/long values (gt or lt etc)?

{"Latitude":33.51882,"Longitude":-93.97484}

It seems like an Object data type is a loose way of storing key value pairs without having to create an entities table etc.  However, I cannot find a way to query this subset.

thanks for any help!